# Update photo using Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I created a table called "directors" using migrations.Then i created the model, view, controller.
In "DirectorController" i wrote crud operations logic for my table. It works until i try to edit a existing record. To be clear it update all informations except the image, it remains the same. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

*Folder "images" exists in public.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo2oW.png)

//Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('directors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->datetime('birth');
        $table->string('town');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

//DirectorController

```
public function update(Request $request, Director $director)
{

    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'birth' => 'required',
        'town' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
        $destinationPath = 'images/';
        $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
    }else{
        unset($input['image']);
    }

    $director->update($input);

    return redirect()->route('directors.index')->with('success', 'Director updated successfully.');


}
```

//DirectorModel

```
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'birth',
    'town',
    'country',
    'image'];

public function movies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Movie::class);
}
```

// edit.blade.php

```
 @extends('directors.layout')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-between mt-5 mb-4">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Edit Director</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('directors.index') }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <div class="first d-flex justify-content-between">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        There were some problems with your input. <br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ( $errors->all() as $error )
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        
    </div>
@endif

<form action="{{ route('directors.update', $director->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>First Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ $director->first_name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Last Name:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ $director->last_name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Birth:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="birth" value="{{ $director->birth }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Birth">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Town:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="town" value="{{ $director->town }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Town">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Country:</strong>
                <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ $director->country }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Image:</strong>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="image">
                <img src="/images/{{ $director->image }}" width="300px">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md12 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-plus"></i> Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@endsection
```

Comment: It seems like you have forgot to put in your form enctype="multiparf/form-data"

Comment: Can you please share your request output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your form as:

```
<form action="{{ route('directors.update', $director->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```